# Add class on page scroll to navbar using bootstrap affix plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap affix plugin here http://versastyles.net/w/ml/site/, so once the page has scrolled down below the main top image the `navbar` will display sticky at the top.

My question is how would I add a class to the `navbar` only once it has scrolled down? E.g. So I can add a background so its visible, as it's currently transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need actually. He already changed it.

For example when you scroll you will have this class: **affix**

Otherwise you will have this one: **affix-top.**

You can do this:

```
.affix > navabar-wrapper{
//styles go here.
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
.affix .navbar-wrapper{
 background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using JQuery, you can add a class to the element ID like below:

```
$( "#elementID" ).addClass( "newClassName anotherClass" );
```

or to the class associated with the element

```
$( ".className" ).addClass( "newClassName anotherClass" );
```

In either case you should place this in a script tag after the element in your HTML